# Compute $\iint_S xz^2dydz+yz^2dzdx+z^3dxdy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

#### Problem

Compute
$$\displaystyle \iint_S xz^2dydz+yz^2dzdx+z^3dxdy$$
where $S$ denotes the outside surface of the common part $\Omega$ of $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq R^2$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 2Rx$.

#### Comment

It would be fair to say this could be solved by **Gauss's Formula**, but how to make the transformation? Anyone can do me a favour?

Comment: but the notation is not wrong.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: The OP's notation is absolutely fine, and you're completely wrong. Please study the subject yourself before claiming something invalid. See, for example [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceIntegral.html) and [here](https://www.math24.net/surface-integrals-vector-fields/).

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 2Rx$.

is actually :
$(x-R)^2+y^2+z^2 \leq R^2$.